# initializing variables before using in java

Tags: java

I have been playing with this piece of code for sometime and it puzzles me why this method call seems to be returning a number although it was not initially set to 0

```
public class MainProg {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FixedCapacitySizeOfStrings s = new FixedCapacitySizeOfStrings(3);
        System.out.println("(" + s.size() + " left on stack)");

    }
}
```

This is the API code

```
public class FixedCapacitySizeOfStrings {
    private String[] a;
    private int N;  

    public FixedCapacitySizeOfStrings(int cap) {
        a = new String[cap];
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return N == 0;
    }

    public int size() {
        return N;  //why is this line doing the right thing?? N was never initialized to 0
    }

    public void push(String item) {
        a[N++] = item;
    }

    public String pop() {
        return a[--N];
    }
}
```

Comment: this is java 101 stuff,

Comment: This is a 101 but valid question.

Comment: Java 101 is really kinda why we're here.

Comment: The point being, SO is not a replacement for a beginner's book on Java or simply reading the documentation / tutorials provided by Oracle. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html <- specifically the part about default values. It took ~ 5 seconds to find that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Primitive instance variables are by default initialized to 0. This includes `int`, `long`, `double`, `float`, `short`, `byte` and `char`. (And all non-primitive instance variables are initialized to `null`)

Note that it's only about instance variables (fields) - local variables are not initialized.

Answer (score 4):

*Instance variables are initialized to default value by the compiler,if you don't provide any initialization*
These are the default values for different types of instance variables.

```
   
data type                    Default value
```

```
boolean                          false
char                             \u0000
int,short,byte / long            0 / 0L
float /double                    0.0f / 0.0d
any reference type                null
```

For more details on [default initialization](http://blog.ajduke.in/2012/03/25/variable-initialization-and-default-values/).

Answer (score 1):

When you are inside of methods, variables must be initialized explicitly. Outside of methods 0 is implicitly the default value integers are initialized to.

So, even though your integer `N` is not being assigned within `FixedCapacitySizeOfStrings` its value is implicitly zero as it's declared as an instance variable (class variable.)

However, your test case complains because the integer `s` wasn't explicitly set to any value, and is being declared within a method.

Comment: Only when declared outside of methods.

Comment: @WilliamMorrison There's no guarantee what the value will be when the variable is declared locally, only class instance fields are guaranteed to be initialized

Comment: @StephenC True. There is when the variable is declared in a class.

Answer (score 0):

```
    FixedCapacitySizeOfStrings s = new FixedCapacitySizeOfStrings(3);
```

it will call the constructor, but before constructor it is called the initialisation code part, which is now empty and `private int N;` takes the 0 value. Than `System.out.println("(" + s.size() + " left on stack)");` will return the 0 value.

Answer (score 0):

it gives s.size()=0 because N is Instance variable and as you know it has default value if you want to correct value then write as

public int size() {

```
    return N=a.length;
         }
```

above give the correct result...